# Why cant we use JS standard methods in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

So this is my html

```
<div ng-controller="simpleAppCtrl">
    <p custom-directive ></p>

</div>
```

and this is my js

```
angular.module("simpleApp", [])
        .directive("customDirective", ()=>{
            return (scope, element,attributes)=>{
                element.css("width","100px");
                element.css("border","2px solid red");
                element.css("height","100px");
                element.style.height = "500px";
        }
        })
        .controller("simpleAppCtrl", $scope =>{

        });
```

so i added some styles to my element in directive using jqLite .css method, and it worked, but adding styles with Javascript STYLE method returns an error saying STYLE is undefined. Also in directive i cant use APPENCHILD method on element, but i can use APPEND (which is jqLite method again). So why we cant use most of JS normal functions and instead we need to use jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element` is jqLite object thus `.css()` worked. To work with DOM element first get its reference using `[0]` then you can manipulate its style property.

```
element[0].style.height = "500px";
```

Comment: So every time i want to do some manipulations i need to refer to [0] , or use jqLite methods. Thanks for information. Although it's still strange for me why they did so